# How to make Telegram Instant View wait for page to render javascript?

Tags: reactjs, telegram, isomorphic-javascript

I want to create a template for my blog, which is written in React and is rendered on the client-side.

I wonder, is there a way to hint the Telegram Instant View that I want it to fetch and execute client-side javascript and wait until it renders dynamic page content, before starting to process my Instant View template and extracting elements from it with XPath?

As a workaround I had to implement isomorphic server-side rendering so far.

Comment: I don't think that possible, from the same reason that Groosha mentioned about the dynamic generating. As far as I know, the IV bot is a backend bot which we do not have access to, nor _exactly_ know what it does. You might want to try to ask it in the [IV Chat](https://t.me/IVpublic), maybe someone there would know better!

Answer (score 2):

There is no "Telegram IV bot" available in API or something like that. Instead you should got [InstantView documentation](https://instantview.telegram.org) and create a template yourself.

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to add "native" support for IV on your site, after you make a template, you can extract an `rhash` parameter while using "Check in Telegram" feature in IV editor. After you finish your template, using links `"https://t.me/iv?url=YOUR_URL&rhash=YOUR_RHASH"` will show people an Instant View article from `YOUR_URL`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, @Groosha, but your answer is a bit off the scope of my question. The point of my question was: is it possible to make the bot wait for the scripts on page to render the content first and start parsing my template for Instant View only after dynamic content is created. I didn't find any way to do this yet, so I'm relying on my server-side rendering currently.

Comment: I see you don't understand how Instant View works. There is Telegram's own crawler which parses links shared via Telegram and if a domain supports Instant View, the template is applied. Since your domain doesn't support Instant View, you cannot add IV support to your website rather than making your own template on instantview.telegram.org and sending a specially formatted link (as I wrote in my answer)

Comment: I do understand how IV works and I did create an IV template for my domain here: https://instantview.telegram.org/. The problem is that by the time my template is processed by the IV bot, dynamically rendered DOM elements of my page (created with javascript, on client side, not on server side) don't exist yet, so they can't be extracted with my template's XPath selectors and shown in the resulting Instant View. My question was: is it possible to tell IV bot to wait for client-side javascript to render dynamic content of my page first (in template configuration).

Comment: Then your webpage is unsupported for Instant View, as seen on their own [Checklist](https://instantview.telegram.org/checklist#2-iv-targets-must-not-generate)

Comment: Again, this is not exactly true. My website is a single-page application (as many sites nowadays), all its content is rendered dynamically, but it's not changing long-term (it's not like Medium's wall of posts, updated all the time, thus un-crawlable). So it's perfectly ok to be analysed by a smarter bot - e.g. Google bot manages to fully index it. Unfortunately, this might not be possible with Telegram IV bot. That's why I'm asking this question - may be it's possible to hint the bot to wait for the page to render. For now I have to pre-render those dynamic elements on server-side.

Comment: @BorisBurkov as far as I understand telegram IV bot doesn't execute js at all. I created several templates for IV and I noticed that IV bot uses the page source as if JavaScript is disabled on it. So I think they just parse raw HTML and not bother with anything else

Comment: @BorisBurkov it's just an idea, but maybe you can detect if the page is requested by IV bot (for example by UserAgent?) and then if you have ability to do server-side rendering, you could create special static version of article-like pages on your site specially for IV bot.

Comment: @JanjaapRee Unfortunately this didn't work. I even created a server-side rendered (isomorphic) React app, but still to no avail.